How to draw a box around the text which can overlap with the other text?
For example, if I use
AAAAAAAAAAA\
AAAA\fbox{AAA}AAAA\
AAAAAAAAAAA
it gives
However, I want to effect as follow(red box,line width controlable),
which the frame may be resizable but the original text spacing will not be changed


You could use the tikzmark library:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
AAAAAAAAAAA

AAAA\tikzmarknode{foo}{AAA}AAAA

AAAAAAAAAAA

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,line width=2pt] ([shift={(-0.3,-0.3)}]foo.south west) rectangle  ([shift={(0.3,0.3)}]foo.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}



With so many parameters, a key-value interface seems the best.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { weixiao/bigfbox }
 {
  color .tl_set:N  = \l__bigfbox_color_tl,  % frame color
  thick .dim_set:N = \l__bigfbox_thick_dim, % frame thickness
  ht    .dim_set:N = \l__bigfbox_ht_dim,    % height (above the baseline)
  dp    .dim_set:N = \l__bigfbox_dp_dim,    % depth (below the baseline)
  pad   .dim_set:N = \l__bigfbox_pad_dim,   % padding left and right
  color .initial:n  = red,
  thick .initial:n  = 0.8pt,
  pad   .initial:n  = 0.5em,
 }


\NewDocumentCommand{\bigfbox}{O{#1}m}
 {% #1 = options, #2 = text
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { weixiao/bigfbox } {#1}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{\l__bigfbox_thick_dim}
  \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{
    \hspace{-\dim_eval:n {\l__bigfbox_pad_dim+\l__bigfbox_thick_dim}}
    \smash{\color{\l__bigfbox_color_tl}\fbox{\color{currentcolor}
      \rule{0pt}{\l__bigfbox_ht_dim} % height
      \rule[-\l__bigfbox_dp_dim]{0pt}{0pt} % depth
      \hspace{\l__bigfbox_pad_dim}
      #2
      \hspace{\l__bigfbox_pad_dim}
  }}}
  \phantom{#2} % to avoid problems

  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

AAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
AAAABBBAAAA\\
AAAAAAAAAAA 

\bigskip

AAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
AAAA\bigfbox[ht=1.8\baselineskip,dp=1.2\baselineskip]{BBB}AAAA\\
AAAAAAAAAAA 

\bigskip

AAAAAAAAAAA\\ 
AAAA\bigfbox[
  thick=2pt,
  color=green!90!blue,
  ht=1.8\baselineskip,
  dp=1.2\baselineskip,
  pad=0pt
]{BBB}AAAA\\
AAAAAAAAAAA 

\end{document}



The \pdfliteral primitive creates a dimensionless drawing, so you don't have to worry about lineskip, spacing around the text etc. The rectangle can be created by PDF primitive re, line width is set by PDF primitive w and color for stokes is set by PDF primitive RG.
The following example can be processed with OpTeX:
\newdimen\vertsize     \vertsize=2.5em   % vertical size of the rectangle
\newdimen\botmargin    \botmargin=.9em   % rectangle is lowered by this size
\newdimen\horizmargin  \horizmargin=.3em % left and right space between text and the rectangle
\newdimen\linew        \linew=1.5pt      % line width
\def\framecolor{1 0 0} % RGB Red         % RGB color

\def\myframe#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
   \pdfliteral{q \bp{\linew} w \framecolor\space RG
      \bp{-\horizmargin} \bp{-\botmargin} \bp{\wd0+2\horizmargin} \bp{\vertsize} re S Q}%
   \box0
}

AAAAAAAAAAA\nl
AAAA\myframe{BBB}AAAA\nl
AAAAAAAAAAA 

\bye

